# Flexbox Ordering. Splitting a column

Tags: flexbox

I want to achieve the following, changing my page layout for mobile/desktop using Flexbox.

I am trying to achieve the following using Flexbox ordering:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBXpJ.jpg

Hope this makes sense?

Comment: Please post the code you've tried.

Comment: FYI, this is in Wordpress, so 1 and 2 are in the sidebar whereas 3 is in the single.php.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way of doing this using flexbox. **[Here is the working demo.](http://jsbin.com/sehiso/3/edit?html,css,output)**

```
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="item menu">Menu</div>
  <div class="item sidebar">Sidebar</div>
  <div class="item content">Content</div>
</div>

.main-container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  border: 5px solid gray;
}

.menu {
  flex-basis: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.sidebar {
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 200px;
}

.content {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .main-container {
    flex-wrap: no-wrap;
    height: 100%;
  }

  .item {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .sidebar, .content {
    flex-basis: auto;
  }
}
```